# Unable to fetch ALL photos in which I have been tagged

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

I am writing an app in which I am trying to access all the photos in which I have been tagged. When I look at the "Photos of you" section on my facebook profile, there are 165 such photos. But when I log into the app as myself (get an access token with the user_photos and friends_photos permissions), I can only fetch 95 photo objects.

After some visual inspection it seems that I can access photos uploaded by my friends (in which I am tagged) if they have shared it with "Friends". If they have shared it with "Custom", my app is unable to pull them even though I can see the photos using my profile.

The facebook developer section simply says that I can get ALL photos in which I have been tagged by using "me/photos" in my graph API call.

Does anyone know why I can only see some of my tagged photos and if my friends' sharing technique is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 user privacy settings on Facebook which would prevent that data coming back from the API - one is if they completely disable platform, and the other is 'How people bring your info to apps they use' - both settings are on the privacy settings page of their profiles ( https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy - click 'Apps and Websites')

To check for the first case, try to access `https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID_OF_FRIEND_THAT_UPLOADED_PHOTO}` - if the answer is 'false' instead of their basic details, they've completely disabled all API access to their account

I don't believe there's any explicit way to check for the other case